# 404 Error is given for the following htaccess Code

Tags: .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.elancemart\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://elancemart.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^services/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) service_details.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z-]+) category.php?catSlug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) blog/article.php?id=$1&&slug=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^verify/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) verify.php?verify=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^services services.php
RewriteRule ^services/page/([\d])$ /services.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^funds add-funds.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^article-sitemap\.xml/?$ article-sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I am getting 404 error when hitting services/page/([\d+])$ /services.php?page=$1

The file exists, though When I change the rewrite rule to service/page/([\d+])$ it is working fine, I need services in the URL, not service.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: the service rule with pagination gives 404 error

Comment: `[\d+]` - the `+` belongs outside of the square brackets, if it is supposed to be a quantifier. The way you have written it, this would allow for _one_ character out of the class of "digits and the plus sign".

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules in your htaccess file. I have put 3 of `services` rules one after another to make it easy looking.

Also make sure your htaccess file is present along side with servcies.php file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.elancemart\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://elancemart.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^services/(\w+)/?$ service_details.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^services/?$ services.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^services/page/(\d+)/?$ services.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ category.php?catSlug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/(\w+)/?$ blog/article.php?id=$1&&slug=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^verify/(\w+)/?$ verify.php?verify=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^funds/?$ add-funds.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml/?$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article-sitemap.xml/?$ article-sitemap.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: I am getting 500 error for service_details and service pagination after trying your changes

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, what is the url you are hitting? Do you have any other rules apart from these ones?

Comment: These are all of the rules that I have, for pagination I am hitting `/services/page/1` and for service details I am hitting `/services/xyz-12-drf`

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, ok, could you please do let me know path of your htaccess file along with your htaccess rules file path?

Comment: htaccess file path is at the root of the domain.

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, please post complete path of php files and htaccess files.

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, could you please do let me know on these details?